# Touches priority in cocos2d/cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am trying to play around with touches in [cocos2d-x](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x) . I have question on the priority of the touches for example , When I use `CCMenuItemSprite` or `CCControlButton`which are added on the Layer which has `setTouchEnabled(true)`

or even If I put a 
What I found is touch is not first given to `ccTouchesBegan` (...I mean Layer) instead it is taken by `CCMenuItemSprite` or `CCCOntrolButton` call backs .

Moreover , If I add an extra layer top on all the layers and `setTouchEnable` (True) same results I get 
touches are first given to menuitem and control button which after touch swallows the touches.

Is there any way by which we can change the priority of touches ? or 
Is there any way by which I can override `CCControlButton` or `CCMEnuItemSprite` ...ccTouchesBegan or moved 
after all I want the touch location of `CCMenuItem` or `CControlButton`
otherwise I have to reconsider the `CCSprite` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

overwrite your CCLayer's method

```
YOUR_LAYER::registerWithTouchDispatcher{
    CCTouchDispatcher::sharedDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, INT_MIN, true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find this in CCMenu.h

```
enum {
    //* priority used by the menu for the event handler
    kCCMenuHandlerPriority = -128,
};
```

so the default priority of the menu is set to -128, if you want to make some layers detect touch before CCMenu, try to set their priority to less than -128

Answer (score 0):

Which would first detect the touches only depends on the priority of the Widget, I think why you had been confused is that you may think it is depended on Zorder of the Widget.So, you can change the priority of the layer you added,and ensure the priority is less than the priority of the menuitems,which is -128 in the Cococs2d-x.

CCLayer.h

```
/** priority of the touch events. Default is 0 */
virtual void setTouchPriority(int priority);
```

CCMenu.h

```
enum {
    //* priority used by the menu for the event handler
    kCCMenuHandlerPriority = -128,
};
```